# Indice fuera de los límites de la matriz

Tags: c#, array

tengo una algoritmo que usa vectores, pero me sale el error índice fuera de los límites de la matriz en vectorB[0] = "A";
Lo raro, es que el error salía primero en el vectorA, ahora, sale en el vectorB

```
String[] vectorA = new String[4];            
            String[] vectorB = new String[3];            
            String[] vectorComprobarParidad = new String[4];
            bool sirve = false;
            string enMayuscula = "";

            vectorA[0] = "A";
            vectorA[1] = "b";
            vectorA[2] = "c";
            vectorA[3] = "D";
            vectorA[4] = "E";

            vectorB[0] = "A";
            vectorB[1] = "B";
            vectorB[2] = "D";
            vectorB[3] = "E";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente el compilador te está avisando que estás pasando el índice,

```
String[] vectorB = new String[3];
```

Al decirle que tendrá el tamaño 3, quiere decir que para recorrerlo son:

```
0, 1, 2
```

En su defecto al decirle que tendrá el tamaño 4, quiere decir que para recorrerlo son:

```
0, 1, 2, 3
```

Por ello

**vectorB[3] = "E";**
**vectorA[4] = "E";**

Te lanza ese error.

[image: Posiciones]

Comment: Eso era... muchas gracias @teamzz111